# Is there a way to SELECT distinct and intersect with related subqueries in single query?

Tags: mysql, subquery, distinct

I have a table with products related to an idpage like this:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| idPage | idProduct | inputedName | inputedCode |
+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|     25 |        60 | x           | 8924        |
|     26 |        65 | y           | 105555      |
|     26 |        70 | z           | 105555      |
|     27 |        33 | a           | 14151112    |
|     27 |        34 | a           | 14151112    |
|     27 |        22 | a           | 14151112    |
|     27 |        17 | b           | OS987456    |
|     27 |        18 | c           |             |
|     27 |        17 |             |             |
|     27 |        23 | a           | 14151112    |
+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

There is no id Unique.

The user input InputedName and InputedCode on a form.

What I want to do on page view is select DISTINCT combination of InputedName x Inputed Code and intersect or inner join (or whatever) with all related itens to show something like:

```
In idPage=27:
- a 141511112 (inputedName, inputedCode)
-- 33 (idProduct)
-- 34
-- 22
-- 23
- b OS987456
-- 17        
- c (null)
-- 18
- (null)(null)
-- 17
```

Is there a great way to do that or the basic way is the best? Basic way, I mean, I'm using PHP. I would first select Distinct combination of inputedName with inputedCode (I still don't know how to do it with my table) and into while command of PHP I would do another query. In this case it would do 5 queries. I don't think it is a ellegant solution, but as I know mysql is powerful, maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused of what you are asking for but let me give this a try:

```
SELECT  inputedName, inputedCode, GROUP_CONCAT(idProduct)
FROM    sampleTable
WHERE   idPage = 27
GROUP BY inputedName, inputedCode
order by COALESCE(inputedname, 'z'),   -- this part is optional
         COALESCE(inputedCode, 'z')    -- this part is optional
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo (Click Here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a7f/4)

Comment: Great, John, and great website for SQL tests! Didn't know that. I'm pretty sure I did a bad done question, sorry! If I have more fields in this table, as I added here: [sqlfiddle demo edited](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc9f) - day and color fields - Should I do another query to get each this values to use in php?

Comment: Thank you @Leo. Is this the query you arelooking for? [*SQLFiddle Demo Link*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc9f/6 "Added GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `color`)")